# how to write a gradle build file for c to create a shared object library (.so) file?

Tags: c, gradle, shared-objects

how to write a gradle build file for c code to create a shared object library (.so) file ?
For creating C executables i can use the below , please guide for creating .so files

```
apply plugin : 'c' 

model { 
    components {
        main(NativeExecutableSpec)   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `NativeLibrarySpec` instead of a `NativeExecutableSpec` as described at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html#sec:building_a_library